# What is the probability of someone trying to take money out of an empty safe if the digital reading on the safe might be outdated?

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

Suppose there is a safe which automatically keeps track of how many \$1 bills are inside of it. This safe is shared between two people. Whenever one of the people accesses the safe, they take out a \$1 bill. The safe is slow meaning that the balance displayed on the safe's digital display is only refreshed every X minutes. When the safe is finally emptied of all the money by one of the two people, there is a period of time P `(0 < P < X)` during which the other person doesn't yet know and may attempt to try to withdraw a bill despite it being empty. The two people withdraw the \$1 bills at different independent average rates (U1 and U2 bills per minute) and they won't attempt to withdraw a bill if they know the safe is empty. If the safe currently contains Y \$1 bills, then what's the probability that, in the next D minutes, one of the people will unknowingly attempt to withdraw a bill while it is empty?

Comment: Welcome to MSE!  In general you want to show your work in questions here, so we don't waste time explaining things you already know, etc.  What have you tried?

Comment: Sorry this problem seems to be above my pay grade so I thought someone might be interested in helping me solve it or pointing me in the right direction!

I might be confident enough to give it an attempt if it was simpler, such as if it was only looking to find the probability that the safe would be emptied in D minutes. I assume there's some way of working out the probability of the sum of two poisson distributions reaching some number in some duration of time. Maybe it could actually be reduced to a single poisson problem by simply summing the rates first.